# How to run a recorded (HTML) selenium test from .NET

Tags: c#, testing, selenium

I run Selenium tests with Selenium RC from .NET (c#).

In some cases, I would like to keep the test case source as HTML (to be able to modify it from Selenium IDE), but I would like to run/include these tests from my c# unit tests.

Maybe it is obvious, but I can't find the API method in the Selenium Core to achieve this. Any idea how to do that?

(I think the "includePartial" command in Selenium on Rails does the thing that I would need, but for c#.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have asked this question some time ago, and since then I have moved forward in automated functional testing, more to the BDD/ATDD/Specification by Example direction with [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org).

I only realize it now however that I have implemented a solution for this concrete question during my experiments. I share my solution, maybe can help others.

I have created a small parser and an interpreter for the Selenium html files (you can download it from here: http://bit.ly/ciTMA2). Besides the implementation, these classes add some extension methods to the Selenium's ICommandProcessor interface. Base on that, a test can look like this:

List commands = SeParser.ParseSeFile(@"HomePageTest.html");
selenium.Processor.InterpretCommands(commands);
selenium.Processor.AssertNoVerifyErrors();

(The InterpretCommands and the AssertNoVerifyErrors are custom extension methods.)

Comment: Did you blog anyplace about this?  I see the code, but I'm not sure how to get started with it.

Comment: Playing around with the parser you created, I noticed quite large difference between number of commands supported by WebDriverCommandProcessor and Selenium IDE. i.e. there is no ClickAndWait. Have you tried runnning your existing scripts against webdriver powered commandprocessor? And if yes - how've you resolved discrepancies?

Comment: (I also don't have any documentation or post for this, sorry.) In the meanwhile I use a different approach: started with SpecFlow (http://www.specflow.org) OSS project. Have a look at that...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there was a way to do this the last time I used Selenium RC .NET

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format when working in Selenium IDE by going to Options-> Format and then set it to the language of your choice. It means that you can create c# tests without having to convert them as you go. You can still rightclick and choose your command and it will update to c# in the IDE.

I think thats what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could parse the xhtml of the test and use .NET reflection to convert it to method calls, but it requires some work from your side